# Calling a function onclick start and onclick stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below functions to start and stop spin.Basically I am trying to add an Autospin button and tried below approach but its not working.Start function is working but stop not working.

```
var nIntervId;
this._onAutoSpin = function(){
  s_oGame.onSpin();
  nIntervId = setInterval(this._onAutoSpin, 10 * 1000);
};

this._offAutoSpin = function(){
  clearInterval(nIntervId);
};
```

Comment: Anyone please help me for the same. thanks

Comment: Can you please share your stop function

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala it's in the question already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're recursively starting a new interval every time it fires, therefore you only stop the latest timer, not the previous.

To fix this change your logic so that there is no possible recursion and there is only ever one interval running:

```js
function Foo() {
  var nIntervId;

  this._onAutoSpin = function() {
    nIntervId = setInterval(this._doAutoSpin, 1 * 1000); // modified for demo
  }

  this._doAutoSpin = function() {
    console.log('spinning...');
  };

  this._offAutoSpin = function() {
    console.log('stopped');
    clearInterval(nIntervId);
  };
}

var foo = new Foo();
foo._onAutoSpin();

setTimeout(foo._offAutoSpin, 5000); // stop after 5 seconds
```

If you want to do this recursively then you need to use `setTimeout()`. You also need to cache the `this` reference so that it is maintained within the successive calls:

```js
function Foo() {
  var nIntervId;

  this._onAutoSpin = function() {
    var _this = this;
    
    console.log('spinning...');
    nIntervId = setTimeout(function() {
      _this._onAutoSpin();
    }, 1 * 1000); // modified for demo
  }

  this._offAutoSpin = function() {
    console.log('stopped');
    clearInterval(nIntervId);
  };
}

var foo = new Foo();
foo._onAutoSpin();

setTimeout(foo._offAutoSpin, 5000); // stop after 5 seconds
```

Comment: I have to handle this onclick button and as I can see its running only 5 times. onAutoSpin() should call recursively  until I stop it

Comment: It's only running 5 times because I used a `setTimeout()` to automatically stop the timer after 5 seconds.

Comment: I edited the answer to show you how to make the calls recursively if you'd prefer to do it that way

Comment: Thanks Rory, I am trying your code and update you in few min

Comment: Its working in separate html file but not working in my Slot Game. May be I am doing something wrong. I am checking. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` because `setInterval` creates a new timer every time without destroying the last one.

```
var nIntervId;
this._onAutoSpin = function(){
  s_oGame.onSpin();
  nIntervId = setTimeout(this._onAutoSpin, 10 * 1000);
};

this._offAutoSpin = function(){
  clearTimeout(nIntervId);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have tried setTimeout() but its running only two times